# Why the authentication should be implemented in a filter and not in a controller?

Tags: security, spring-security, jwt

Following a good tutorial about how to implement JWT authentication in a Spring Boot application (https://auth0.com/blog/implementing-jwt-authentication-on-spring-boot/), I have seen that the /login is handled by a filter and not by a controller. And this is not a Bruno's caprice, Spring is offering itself a filter (UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter and so).

Why use a filter? Is it because it is placed before the authorization filter and this way we can intercept a new login attempt without being affected by the authentication filter?

Thanks!
Enric

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The filter chain is one of `spring-security` core-concepts. The intro of the `spring-security` [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/security-filter-chain.html) explains the benefits as following:

> Spring Security's web infrastructure is based entirely on standard servlet filters. [...]
>
> Spring Security maintains a filter chain internally where each of the filters has a particular responsibility and filters are added or removed from the configuration depending on which services are required.

Generally speaking: You use a framework like `spring` for handling standard application-flows like in your case authentication and login. The concept of `spring-security` for dealing with this is the filter chain. Due to the fact that using a framework comes alongside some payoffs (e.g. overhead), it is highly recommended to use the possibilities the framework offers you.

In your case the `/login` is handled by the [`UsernamePassworAuthenticationFilter`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/security-filter-chain.html). This filter brings along some standard logic for login-proceeding and handles authentication and is therefore not handled by a controller.

> The filter (`UsernamePassworAuthenticationFilter`) calls the configured `AuthenticationManager` to process each authentication request. The destination following a successful authentication or an authentication failure is controlled by the `AuthenticationSuccessHandler` and `AuthenticationFailureHandler` strategy interfaces, respectively. The filter has properties which allow you to set these so you can customize the behaviour completely